# Different kind of Exception not being caught?

Tags: clojure

```lisp
; common/math.clj
(defn nths
  "Returns a collection of values for each idx in idxs. Throws an error if any one idx is out of bounds."
  [coll idxs]
  (map #(nth coll %) idxs))

; nrepl
common.math> (try (/ 1 0)
     (catch Exception e (prn "in catch"))
     (finally (prn "in finally")))
"in catch"
"in finally"
nil
common.math> (try (nths '(5 6 7 8 9) '(0 5))
     (catch Exception e (prn "in catch"))
     (finally (prn "in finally")))
"in finally"
IndexOutOfBoundsException   clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom (RT.java:784)
common.math> (nths '(5 6 7 8 9) '(0 1 3))
(5 6 8)
common.math> *clojure-version*
{:major 1, :minor 5, :incremental 0, :qualifier "alpha4"}
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong in the second expr. I was expecting it would again print:

```
"in catch"
"in finally"
```

The same thing occurs when running a unittest:

```
lein test unittest.common.math

FAIL in (test-nths) (math.clj:87)
expected: (thrown? IndexOutOfBoundsException (nths (quote (5 6 7 8 9)) (quote (0 5))))
  actual: nil
```

which should pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nths is lazy so the function actually runs when your repl tries to print the result:

```
core> (def result (try (nths '(5 6 7 8 9) '(0 5))
                        (catch Exception e (prn "in catch"))
                        (finally (prn "in finally"))))
"in finally"
#'core/result
core> result
; Evaluation aborted.
```

you can either catch the exception in `nths` or as makes more sense catch it when you use it

```
rsadl.core> (def result (try (nths '(5 6 7 8 9) '(0 5))
                        (catch Exception e (prn "in catch"))
                        (finally (prn "in finally"))))
"in finally"
#'core/result
core> (try (println result) (catch Exception e (prn "in catch")))
("in catch"
nil
```

or as number23_cn points out you can realize the result with at the time you create it so long as you don't need it to be lazy for some other reason.

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't think of the repl as trying to evaluate the return value of `try`, namely the lazy list from `(nths '(5 6 7 8 9) '(0 5))`.

Comment: I call this "the lazy bug" and it has bitten me in soo many ways ... ps: technically the REPL is only trying to print the value, it's the lazy  seq that causes it to be evaluated then

Answer (score 1):

```
(try (doall (nths '(5 6 7 8 9) '(0 5)))
     (catch Exception e (prn "in catch"))
     (finally (prn "in finally")))
"in catch"
"in finally"
nil
user=>
```

because map return lazy-seq?